# How do i list the users and their roles in asp.net core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core

I got to list all the users by using this in my controller:

```
public IActionResult ListUsers(){

    var users = _application.Users.ToList();

    return View(users);
}
```

but i can't seem to be able to add the ROLE field from the aspnetroles table.. It should be a simple join but every attempt i have tried failed, like this one:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
    {

        var applicationUser = await _context.ApplicationUser.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        var model = new UsuariosViewModel
        {
            CC = applicationUser.CC,
            Apellido = applicationUser.Apellido,
            Nombre = applicationUser.Nombre,
            Rol = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(applicationUser)
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

how should the method look like?

And also, how should the view look like after the join?

Comment: there is no join that will work since they were disconnected from either in asp.net core 2.0 \ ef-core 2.0 what you have is the best its going to get.  Loop users and get each user's roles.

Answer (score 0):

User may has more than one role

This is action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UsersRolesList()
    {

        var AllUsers = _application.Users.ToList();

        UsersAndRolesViewModel UserAndRoleViewModel = new UsersAndRolesViewModel();

        List<UserAndRoleViewModel> AllUsersAndRoles = new List<UserAndRoleViewModel>();

        foreach (var usr in AllUsers)
        {
            var model = new UserAndRoleViewModel
            {
                UserName = usr.UserName,

                Roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(usr)
            };

            AllUsersAndRoles.Add(model);
        }

        UserAndRoleViewModel.UserAndRole = AllUsersAndRoles;

        return View(UserAndRoleViewModel);
    }
```

and this view:

```
@model UsersAndRolesViewModel

<table style="width:100%">
    @foreach (var usr in Model.UserAndRole)
    {
       <tr>
            <td>
                UserName:
                @usr.UserName
            </td>
            <td>
                Roles:
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var role in usr.Roles)
                        {
                            <td>
                                 Role Name: @role
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
       </tr>
   }
</table>
```

this is ViewModel

```
public class UserAndRoleViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }

}

public class UsersAndRolesViewModel
{
    public List<UserAndRoleViewModel> UserAndRole { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this was incorrect. Context.User is not something used in .net core as i understand from multiple articles, and there are many syn. errors in the code. Have you tested it?

Comment: I updated the code, just i change context with _application as you define in your app. yes i tested it now and it work right with me